# State not passing to the child component reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to pass a state as props to another component. The child component (a button on the page) isn't receiving any props. I did a `console.log` to print the props received from the parent but I get an empty  object `{}`. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is an excerpt from my code:

**loan.js (Parent)**

```
<ForecloseBtn id={this.state.lead_id} foreclose={this.state.isForeclosed } test="xyz"/>
```

**ForecloseBtn.js (Child)**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';

    class ForecloseBtn extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            console.log(this.props);
            this.state = {
                lead_id: this.props.id,
                isForeclosed: this.props.foreclose,
                sample: this.props.test
            };
        }

        render() {

            return (
                ......
            )
        }
    };


    const App = () => (


        <ForecloseBtn />

    );

    export default App;
```

Comment: `foreclose=this.state.isForeclosed }` -> `foreclose={this.state.isForeclosed}`

Comment: `console.log(this.props);` -> `console.log(props);`

Comment: you should have multiple errors in console with your current code...

Comment: @Mykybo I had copied the code here wrongly. I have made the edit.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that it will be easier for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a propTypes like this

```
static propTypes = {    
id: object.isRequired,
foreclose: func.isRequired,        
}
```

and for sure

```
import {  
func, 
object,  
} from 'prop-types'
```

Comment: That's not what proptypes are for

Answer (score 0):

```
You can check my fiddle
```

[Pass props to child](https://jsfiddle.net/ghrsLpqj/1/)

Hope this helps.